# multiple jquery datetime as form field not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datetime

when I create form where is only one "datetime" field :

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker">
```

is all right, but when i have multiply "datetime" field in same form:

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker">
<input type="text" id="datepicker">
```

this not working. JQuery datepicker works only for first input, for second is not shown. What is problem?

In my main layout page I have:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="{$basePath}/js/main.js"></script>
```

In my main.js :

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({dateFormat: "yy-m-d"});
```

Comment: Use class instead of id

Comment: See my answer for this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34383072/how-can-i-get-values-from-hidden-inputs-with-the-same-id/34383200#34383200

Comment: thanks, for class is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your code for use class:

```
<input type="text" class="datepicker">
<input type="text" class="datepicker">
```

And execute your script so:

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({dateFormat: "yy-m-d"});
```

Or use differents IDs:

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker">
<input type="text" id="datepicker2">
```

And execute you script so:

```
$('#datepicker, #datepicker2').datepicker({dateFormat: "yy-m-d"});
```

Answer (score 0):

Both of your input form fields have the same ID. Give the second one a different ID, like datepicker2, then you can call datpicker on that field using that ID.

```
$('#datepicker2').datepicker({dateFormat: "yy-m-d"}); // The second datepicker
```

Instead of using IDs, you can also use class names:

```
<input type="text" class="datepicker">
<input type="text" class="datepicker">

 $('.datepicker').datepicker({dateFormat: "yy-m-d"}); // All datepickers with class "datepicker"
```

Comment: okay. but I think that is not very good solution, because when i will have more datepickers elements always I have to have in my code something like this : $('#datepicker1').datepicker({dateFormat: "yy-m-d"});, $('#datepicker2').datepicker({dateFormat: "yy-m-d"}); $('#datepicker3').datepicker({dateFormat: "yy-m-d"}); There is any other solution that i will have only one statement for all datepickers?

Comment: Yes, it just depends on what you intend to do with the datepickers. If you want to have different settings for each one then this would be the way to do it. If you want to keep the same setting for all, then switch to class names.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have two DOM elements with the same id. You may use class instead:

```
<input type="text" class="datepicker">
<input type="text" class="datepicker">
```

And in main.js:

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({dateFormat: "yy-m-d"});
```

Answer (score 0):

you simply cant have ids with the same name. change them to classes or use unique names for you ids